# How to render a list of lists to HTML with Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to collect some soccer game data to a single table by python3, jinja2 to a stylized HTML template page. I'm just beginner in programming and I may have made some mistake on transferring the data.

I tried to print the result out it seems ok like

```
mylist=[[['2019-04-27', '03:00'], ['liverpool', 'liverpool', 'EP', 'tag'], ['live']],
[['2019-04-27', '10:00'], ['GSW', 'LAC', 'NBA', 'tags', 'tags'], ['live1', 'live2']],
[['2019-04-27', '19:30'], ['hotspurs', 'WH', 'EP'], ['live']]]
```

but when I try to render HTML with jinja2, like
    `print(template.render(mylist))`
it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:/学习/pythonLearning/zhibo8_v4.py", line 57, in <module>
    print(template.render(showListReady))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1003, in render
    vars = dict(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

I think it could be something wrong in my HTML template, like

```
        <tbody>
        {% for game in showListReady %}
        {% for date, time, teamA, teamB, tags, broadcast in game %}
        <tr>
            <td class="firstColumn">
                <div class="dateClass">${date}</div>
                <div class="timeClass">${time}</div>
            </td>
            <td class="secondColumn">
                <span class="teamName">${teamA}</span>
                <span><img src="images/xxxx.png"></span>
                <span class="VS">VS</span>
                <span><img src="images/xxxx.png"></span>
                <span class="teamName">${teamB}</span>
                <span class="leagueName">${tags}</span>
            </td>
            <td class="thirdColumn">
                <span class="broadcast">${broadcast}</span>
              </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

hope someone could give me some advice, please

Comment: How are you generating `mylist`? One problem that I can see is that the line `date, time, teamA, teamB, tags, broadcast in game` expects 6 elements in the `game`, but there are only 3. Second, the tags and broadcast info appear to be multiple elements in a list, but it might be better if they were a single comma separated  list each.

Comment: thanks, I may see something sparkled... should I change 'mylist' structure? but I still don't know how to locate a value in a list in jinja.  what should I do in jinja2 to express like python's 'mylist[0][1]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
print(template.render(showListReady=showListReady))
```